# Странное оформление прямой речи в классике

Tags: прямая-речь

Недавно прочитала «Преступление и наказание», сейчас читаю «Мастера и Маргариту», и во всей прочитанной мною русской классике я везде встречала подобное (пример из «Мастера и Маргариты»):
*— Фу ты черт! — воскликнул редактор, — ты знаешь, Иван, у меня сейчас едва удар от жары не сделался!*
После первой фразы стоит восклицательный знак, а значит, предложение закончилось, но следующая фраза Берлиоза начинается с маленькой буквы. Что это значит и почему так? Где правила, объясняющие это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне думается, что такую пунктуацию нельзя признать удачной, правильной.
Есть много версий оформления этого предложения:
перед "чёрт" иногда стоит запятая (как при обращении); "Ты знаешь..." — часто с прописной; в некоторых случаях слова автора "воскликнул редактор" заканчиваются точкой (что верно).
Я бы остановилась на [**таком варианте**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=XJorDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT5&lpg=PT5&dq=%D0%A4%D1%83%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82!%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80,%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C,%20%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD,%20%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F!&source=bl&ots=bjfyus4NNj&sig=ACfU3U1Rl8foQli-zgGchsJ3OaayEJn0fw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcoo-FwLHpAhVDwqYKHZMSBxEQ6AEwCHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%A4%D1%83%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82!%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%2C%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%2C%20%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F!&f=false).

> **— Фу ты черт! — воскликнул редактор. — Ты знаешь, Иван, у меня сейчас едва удар от жары не сделался!** Даже что-то вроде галлюцинации было… — он попытался усмехнуться, но в глазах его еще прыгала тревога, и руки дрожали. Однако постепенно он успокоился, обмахнулся платком и, произнеся довольно бодро: «Ну-с, итак…» — повел речь, прерванную питьем абрикосовой.

Если на месте «разрыва» прямой речи словами автора должен был бы стоять вопросительный или **восклицательный знак** [наш вариант], то этот знак сохраняется перед словами автора и после него ставится тире. При этом **слова автора пишутся со строчной буквы, после них ставятся точка и тире, а вторая часть прямой речи пишется с прописной буквы:**
*«Вот он, край **света! — воскликнул Мохов. — Здорово!** Никогда ещё так далеко не ездил!»* (Ажаев)

[Слова автора внутри прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158) (Розенталь)

**Дополнение** (об отсутствии запятой)

[**Фу ты!**](http://endic.ru/rusphrase/Fu-t--3772.html)  Разг. Экспрес. Употребляется для выражения удивления (обычно с ироническим оттенком).
**[Чёрт](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Chert-67304.html)**, в зн. вводн. сл. и межд. Выражает сильную досаду и раздражение. *Чёрт! стукнул руку! Чёрт! уже десять часов! Ах, чёрт! **Фу (ты) чёрт!** Чёрт знает что такое!* (безобразие! возмутительно!).

Comment: Поздравляю с **25k**!

Comment: А-а! Ой, теперь Вы и меня сосчитали! (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bExSipXIXQ) Благодарю — нечасто увидишь внимание к чужим успехам. Да, я достигла определенной цели (конечно же, поставленной условно).